# 'Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over.' with Microsoft Bot Service with LUIS Template

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created a Bot Service with LUIS template using Node.js, I have trained my luis model with our domain utterances and it was working fine. suddenly from a week time , Am facing weird behavior form the Bot Service, for any request the bot is replying as 'Oops. Something went wrong and we need to start over.' message. Could anyone encountered the similar issue and share your inputs to resolve.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this happening in the emulator or another channel?  Does your model work when testing/training in the LUIS portal?

Comment: @JasonSowers  
It's working well in the emulator and this happening in skype channel? can you hel

Comment: I'm having the same issue. in Slack channel, when users are sending very very long messages with their reports. I just want bot to be silent as key phrase was not found.

Comment: Try sending ' /deleteProfile' to the bot from the client that is having issues (without the quotes).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems#how-do-i-version-the-bot-data-stored-through-the-state-api

Answer (score 0):

When a user query exceeds 500 character Luis gives an error. Check the user message how long it is and then test it in Luis portal. Or please check the subscription key which is used.